# C# is operator, exact behavior of unboxing

Tags: c#

The [C# language specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#the-is-operator) doc about the is operator reads:

> The result of the operation `E is T`, where E is an expression and T is a type, is a boolean value indicating whether E can successfully be converted to type T by a reference conversion, a boxing conversion, or an unboxing conversion. [...]

> [...] let D represent the dynamic type of E as follows:
>
> - If the type of E is a reference type, D is the run-time type of the instance reference by E.
> - If the type of E is a nullable type, D is the underlying type of that nullable type.
> - If the type of E is a non-nullable value type, D is the type of E.
>   The result of the operation depends on D and T as follows:
>   [... goes on with the target type]

Then the documentation goes on with a similar distinction about the target type. Since I'm only interested in the expression's type, I that part and also the null cases that are not relevant for this question.

When I have something like that:

```
object s = "hey";
if (s is string) ...
```

It's the first case that applies.

When I have something like that:

```
int? nullableInt = 10;
if (nullableInt is int) ...
```

It's the second case that applies: E *is* a nullable type and int is its underlying type. Pretty useless.

**But** when i have something like that, that is a value boxed into an object, it seems like there is a missing rule.

```
object o = (int)10;
if (o is int) ...
```

Here the static type of the expression is object, that is a referece type, while its run-time type is a value type.
This is a very (maybe the most) common scenario for type-testing.
Since the static type of the expression is a reference type, it should be the first case that applies.
But when the 'content' of the reference type is a value type, it should apply rules like 2 and 3 for the boxed value, behavior that I confirmed via test.
But this is not what the documentation says; it seems to me that the boxing case is missing.
Is this analysis correct or it's me missing something?

Comment: The static type is not relevant. You have to look back to where it says *"whether `E` can successfully be converted to type `T` by a reference conversion, a boxing conversion, or an unboxing conversion"*. Since `o` can be unboxed to `int` at run time, it fits the third case.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the expression `E` corresponds to your variable `o`. Its (static) type is `object`, and its runtime type is `int`.

Then according to this rule

> If the type of `E` is a reference type, `D` is the run-time type of the
> instance reference by `E`.

the dynamic type `D` of `E` is `int`, since "type" in the antecedent of the rule refers to the *static type*, which in our case is indeed a reference type.

The definition of the `is` operator further specifies

> If `T` is a non-nullable value type, the result is true if `D` and `T` are the same type.

In this case, `T` corresponds to `int` (since your are testing `o is int`). Hence `o is int` is true, since `D` and `T` are both `int`.

Comment: I would say that this "sort of works". That's because they feel the need to extract the underlying type of the nullable type and so they created two cases for value types. But this doesn't apply to the first case, so if the boxed type were "int?", no further extraction of value type would be performed, while in the case of a non boxed value when the runtime type is "int?", they extract "int". So if they think it's important to specify how to extract the underlying type for non-boxed values, they should do so also for boxed ones or I'm allowed to think that boxed are treated differently.

Comment: @AgostinoX Not sure if I follow you. Do you have an example where you still think the rules don't work?

Comment: The second and third rules are made for the sole reason of handling this: int i; and int? i; D is int in both cases. But where do they say the same for object o = (int)10; and object o = (int?)10;  ?? In this case, D should be int for the first and int? for the second.

Comment: That is, the intention seems to be to always compare the underlying type if there is one. But in the case of boxing no underlying type is extract. This is not uniform with the 2nd and 3rd case and not uniform with the target type T that gets processed the same way, that is extracting underlying type if nullable so it never returns "int?".

Comment: A boxed type is never a nullable value type. Nullable value types are unwrapped when boxed. Unboxing will always give the underlying type, never the nullable-wrapped type. This was a last-minute change in C# **2.0** beta 2 (back in 2005). In beta 1, boxing `(int?)null` gave a non-null reference, which didn't compare to `null` as one would expect. It was made last-minute because there was such cognitive dissonance. I still keep a copy of the VS 2005 beta 1 DVD as a piece of history.